# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript, html, css

when trying to press nav-toggle icon to appear the navbar content, i get this error.

```
<nav>
            <button id="nav-toggle" class="hamburger-menu">
                <span class="strip"></span>
                <span class="strip"></span>
                <span class="strip"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="nav-menu-container">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

here is my javascript:

```
<script>
        document.getElementById('nav-toggle').addEventListener('click', function () {
        let navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu-container');
        navMenu.style.display = (navMenu.offsetParent === null  ? 'block' : 'none');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `id` attribute for the `ul` since you are trying to get it using `getElementById`.

```html
<ul id="nav-menu-container">
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined "nav-menu-container" as a class not as an id.

Answer (score 0):

**nav-menu-container** is the name of class but you are accessing it like an id.

```js
document.getElementById('nav-toggle').addEventListener('click', function ()
{
    let navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu-container');
    navMenu.style.display = (navMenu.offsetParent === null  ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

```html
<nav>
    <button id="nav-toggle" class="hamburger-menu">
        <span class="strip"></span>
        <span class="strip"></span>
        <span class="strip"></span>
    </button>
    <ul id="nav-menu-container">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```